# $('#myDataTable').dataTable() is throwing exception

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using DataTables 1.10.7 version. I am creating the datatable using the script as given below:

```
<script data-for="myDataTable" type="application/json">
{"x":{"data":    
[["+jsonIDList+"],["+jsonLocations+"],["+jsonScore+"]],"container":"
ID  Location    Score
","options":{"pageLength":15,"autoWidth":true,"columnDefs":    
[{"className":"dt-right","targets":2}],"order":    
[],"orderClasses":false,"orderCellsTop":true,"lengthMenu":    
[10,15,25,50,100]},"callback":null,"filter":"top","filterHTML":"
<tr>              <td data-type=\"character\" sType=\"html\" 
style=\"vertical-align:             top;\">
</td> <td data-type=\"character\" style=\"vertical-align: top;\">
</td> <td data-type=\"number\" style=\"vertical-align: top;\">
</td></tr>"},"evals":[]}
</script>
```

This is working fine with filtering and searching. I have a requirement to add a new Reset button which when clicked needs to reset the search and filter criteria to default. I am using the below code when reset button

```
<button type="button" onclick="resetmyDataTable();" class="btn btn-default">Reset datatable</button> is clicked
```

```js
function resetmyDataTable() {
    var table = $('#myDataTable').dataTable();
    // Perform a filter
    table.fnFilter('Win');
    table.fnFilter('Trident', 0);
    // Remove all filtering
    table.fnFilterClear();
}
```

But `$('#myDataTable').dataTable()` is throwing exception :

> Unable to get property 'nTable' of undefined or null reference

Below is the call stack during the exception:

```
w - exception line: h(a.**nTable**).trigger(b,e)
I
Anonymous function
each
each
m()
resetmyDataTable()
```

the `w` function having exception:

```
function w(a,b,c,e){var d=[];b&&(d=h.map(a[b].slice().reverse(),function(b)    
{return b.fn.apply(a.oInstance,e)}));null!==c&&    
(b=h.Event(c+".dt"),h(a.nTable).trigger(b,e),d.push(b.result));return d}
```

Appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Could you please add your actual code without the completely human-unreadable escape characters.

Comment: If you had to read this question from another user, would you be able to understand it? Please reformat the code - People here are trying to help and you just making it impossible to understand